# UIImageView image not updating when in tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code which is trying to update a uiimageviews image in a custom tableviewcell after the user has selected an image from their library

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myJourneyPhotoCell") as! MyJourneyPhotoTableViewCell

    cell.imgPhoto.image = image

    cell.setCell(
        image
    )
    tableView.reloadData()

    CustomPhotoAlbum().saveImage(image)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

I know I don't need both

```
cell.imgPhoto.image
```

and

```
cell.setCell
```

but I was trying both methods and neither of them worked. I can print out the image both after the selection in the tableviewcontroller and the tableviewcell classes so I know the image is being sent but it just wont update.

This is my tableviewcell class

```
@IBOutlet weak var imgPhoto: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

func setCell(
    image: UIImage)
{
    self.imgPhoto.image = image
    // self.imgPhoto.image = UIImage(named: "Calendar Active") // Test code
    print(image)
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your code in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are dequeuing a new cell every time your delegate method
didFinishPickingImage is called. You have to keep track of the index path of the cell that is clicked and then use

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyJourneyPhotoTableViewCell // Here the indexPth is the index path of your clicked cell
```

to get the cell's object and then set its image.

Answer (score 0):

Your image isn't set in tableViewCell, Because According to your code the tableView reload before the set image. So Add the reload tableview code after the set of image.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myJourneyPhotoCell") as! MyJourneyPhotoTableViewCell

    cell.imgPhoto.image = image

    cell.setCell(
        image
    )
    CustomPhotoAlbum().saveImage(image)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an image variable in your custom cell class like mentioned below:

```
var image : UIImage!
```

Now assign the picked image to this variable in picker delegate method:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myJourneyPhotoCell") as! MyJourneyPhotoTableViewCell

cell.image = image

CustomPhotoAlbum().saveImage(image)
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

}

Last you need to add below method in your Custom cell class

```
    override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews();

     if(image){
         self.imgPhoto.image = image
     }else{
         self.imgPhoto.image = UIImage.init(named: "DefaultImage")
     } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` of `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` method

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    var image : UIImage!
    image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myJourneyPhotoCell") as! MyJourneyPhotoTableViewCell

    cell.imgPhoto.image = image
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    CustomPhotoAlbum().saveImage(image)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```